# uninitialized constant ContactsController::ContactMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I am trying to use ActiveModel to create a contact us form. When I click submit i get a NameError `uninitialized constant ContactsController::ContactMailer` on line `ContactMailer.new_contact(@contact).deliver`

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    if @contact.valid?
      ContactMailer.new_contact(@contact).deliver
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :message

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :message, presence: true, length: { maximum: 300 }
end
```

Form:

```
<h1>Contact Us</h1>

<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :message %>
  <%= f.text_area :message %>

  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Dumb question, but do you have a file at `app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb`? If not, then you need that. :)

Comment: Ahh I have one for user only, dumb me. Thanks for the obvious point out. Rushing things!

Comment: No prob. This sort of stuff happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our comments, you have not implemented `ContactMailer` yet. You can do so at `app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb`.

You can find out more about [mailers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) in the Rails docs.

(It sounds like you already know how to implement mailers, but you're not the only one who will ever read this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem because the `contact_mailer.rb` file wasn't matching with the class name that i had given to that file.

I renamed my file name i.e from `contacts_mailer.rb` to `contact_mailer.rb` for my class `ContactMailer`